# makefile with creation of c- and h-file from perlscript

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I like to create a `c`- and `h`-file from a perlscript. So i created the following rule:

```
abc.[ch]:
  @perl makestrings abc
```

I got this error message:

```
File `abc.h' does not exist.
```

When i used the rule `abc.h:` it will work.
I think i got a problem that the `c` file is not included afterwards. So i needed to restart make when `abc.h` or `abc.c` are created.

Comment: Does the `perl makestrings abc` work well? It works well for me with a simple script.

Comment: yeah, the script work well. `abc.h` and `abc.c` are created. But if make tries to compile `abc.o` it failed because make couldn't find abc.c although it was created by the script. It seems make coudln't find it in the first place.

Comment: Ah, understand. You didn't say that you want to create `abc.o` from your `abc.c` and `abc.h`. See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

`abc.[ch]` is a wildcard for `abc.c` or `abc.h`. But it is a wildcard, that is, if the files do not exist, it expands as the string `abc.[ch]` (not what you want). And if only one exists, it expands as this one (not what you want). You could try something like:

```
.PHONY: abc_ch
abc_ch: abc.c abc.h

abc.c abc.h:
    @perl makestrings abc
```

Comment: `The wildcard characters in make are ‘*’, ‘?’ and ‘[…]’, the same as in the Bourne shell.` see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, thanks. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why is the `abc_ch` rule needed?

Comment: @Beta It is not. It is just a way to define a default goal (if it is the first target of the Makefile) that builds both files. You can just type `make` and it is the same as `make abc_ch` which is the same as `make abc.c abc.h`.

Comment: I mean, why not have the `abc.c abc.h` rule as the default rule, with exactly the same effect?

Comment: @Beta Because then, the default goal would be only the first of these two targets (`abc.c`), not both.

Comment: Ah! So if the first is up to date, the second will not be built. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Makefile` is correct but you should add a plus rule.

```
abc.o: abc.c abc.h
    ${CC} -o abc.o abc.c
```

In this case `abc.o` requires `abc.c` and `abc.h` too so `make` will create `abc.c` and `abc.h` first and after it try to build `abc.o`.

A plus suggestion: I would add a dependency to `abc.[ch]`: the `makestrings` perl-script. And maybe any other files that are used by `makestrings`.

Comment: There is a rule in my include makefile `makefile.cpu`:    `$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR)` which i think is doing excatly this. Therefore i tought it shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: But I can't see the `%.h` (in the `makefile.cpu`) :) My version contains the `%.h` too.

Comment: Sound correct. But i did a `make clean` and copied `abc.c` so that file was already created before starting make. Everything works fine. I can't find a logical failure.

Comment: I don't understand you. Did you `make clean`? What is "copied" `abc.c`? I thought `abc.c` is created by your `makestrings`. The `makestrings abc` will create `abc.c` and `abc.h`, right?